# Can't find USB to RS232 device on Windows IOT / Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, serial-port, windows-iot-core-10

I have a USB to Serial cable that plugs into a custom built electronics board.

I'm trying to write a UWP app that will 'talk' with it. I have a Raspberry Pi 3, Windows IOT.

I have the capability set:

```
<Capabilities>
  <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
    <Device Id="any">
      <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
    </Device>
  </DeviceCapability>
</Capabilities>
```

I run this code on my local machine and on the remote machine (Pi):

```
string AQS = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromUsbVidPid(0x067B, 0x2303);

DeviceInformationCollection currentDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(AQS); 

var devicesFound = currentDevices.Count;
```

On the Local Machine (x86) it says I have 1 device, connects and chats fine..

On the Remote Machine it says there is 0

I've tried booting the Pi with the device plugged in, plugging while booted - What am I missing here?

**Edit**

I ran a `devcon stack *` in the console and found my device:

```
USB\VID_067B&PID_2303\5&3753427A&0&3
    Name: USB-Serial Controller
    Device is not set up
    Controlling service:
        (none)
```

and `devcon status`:

```
USB\VID_067B&PID_2303\5&3753427A&0&3
    Name: USB-Serial Controller
    The device has the following problem: 28
    Problem status: 0xC0000490
```

Does this mean I need a driver?

Comment: There is a little info about troubleshooting USB serial ports here : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/71d2cf78-2885-4e88-9fa3-3e1655f9947b/serial-port-communication-on-windows-iot-core?forum=WindowsIoT

Comment: @PaulF Thanks for the comment - I've edited my question - does this mean I need a driver or the hardware is simply not compatible?

Comment: _"does this mean I need a driver"_ - maybe _"the hardware is simply not compatible"_ - maybe - Code 28: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/cm-prob-failed-install   - I don't think all USB UART chipsets are supported on Win IOT.

Comment: @PaulF this is proving more difficult than first thought! - I'm trying to find either a generic driver or compatible hardware now :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the [Hardware compatibility list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/hardwarecompatlist), it lists the verified deives which is compatible with Windows IoT Core. It is recommended to use the device in the list.

Comment: One option for Windows IOT Core on the Raspberry Pi is USB to Serial devices supporting the FTDI Chipset